# WHM cPanlel Disk Usage Incorrect

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, cpanel, whm

I have cPanel/WHM installed on a 40gb partition, however WHM shows that 8.9gb out of 9.9gb is in use. How do I correct this?

This is on an AWS EC2 instance. The root volume is configured to 40gb.

After running df -h :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                  9.9G  8.9G  574M  95% /
/dev/hda1              99M   26M   69M  28% /boot
tmpfs                1006M     0 1006M   0% /dev/shm
```

So that shows that the /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 is 9.9GB. However, if I run parted and print the configuration I can see that:

```
Model: QEMU HARDDISK (ide)
Disk /dev/hda: 42.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      32.3kB  107MB   107MB   primary  ext3         boot 
2      107MB   21.5GB  21.4GB  primary               lvm
```

I need the whole 40GB for cPanel/WHM. Why would it limit its self to 1/4 of the disk?

After Running vgs

```
VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
VolGroup00   1   2   0 wz--n- 19.88G    0
```

pvs:

```
PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
/dev/hda2  VolGroup00 lvm2 a--  19.88G    0
```

lvs:

```
LV       VG         Attr   LSize  Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
LogVol00 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 10.22G                                      
LogVol01 VolGroup00 -wi-ao  9.66G
```

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/hda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/hda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/hda2              14        2610    20860402+  8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/dm-0: 10.9 GB, 10972299264 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1333 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Disk /dev/dm-0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/dm-1: 10.3 GB, 10368319488 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1260 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Disk /dev/dm-1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: As per your fdisk -l command, I can see there are free space on your /dev/hda disk. You will have to create new partition from that free space. Please try to create it OR contact your server admin for this.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you checking disk usages in WHM ? Can you please let me know following command out put so that I can assist you on this.

```
df -h
```

Comment: This is what I get: Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      9.9G  8.9G  574M  95% /
/dev/hda1              99M   26M   69M  28% /boot
tmpfs                1006M     0 1006M   0% /dev/shm

Comment: So that shows that the volume is only 9.9G, but if I run parted and print then you can see that my disk is 42.9 GB :Model: QEMU HARDDISK (ide)
Disk /dev/hda: 42.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Answer (score 0):

I think there is free space on your server in LVM partition. Can you please check this with the following command and let me know

```
vgs
pvs
lvs
fdisk -l
```

And if you found any free space in your VolGroup, Then you will have to increase it through lvextend command, You can check it at http://www.24x7servermanagement.com/blog/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-logical-volume/

Comment: I added the results of each of those above.

Comment: I attempted the steps from the link that you sent but I was unable to extend my volume. This is the error I got: Extending logical volume LogVol00 to 30.22 GB
  Insufficient free space: 640 extents needed, but only 0 available